# mousedown drag (specific to topic)

Tags: jquery, drag, mousedown

I know there are a lot of mousedowndrag threads lurking around, but please don't send me to any of them or say "duplicate thread" as I've been using the previous scripts as references,

my fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/V8N7f/

my issue is when people drag the mouse it skips random squares and is not smooth at all!! could somebody supply me with the modified code to address this issue.

Thanks

Owen

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$('.square').mousemove(function(){
    if(clicking == false) 
       return;

    fill(this);
});
```

to

```
$('.square').mouseenter(function(){
    if(clicking == false) 
       return;

    fill(this);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V8N7f/10/)**

Comment: Works nicely in Firefox but still bad in Webkit.

Comment: Looking at the UI, its difficult to get the same result in all the browsers because lot a code execution is going on since so many events are fired in quick succession.